# About UITableView Component

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm new to developing applications for iphone and am studying alone.
I'm trying to make a view equal to the link below:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B26lA9znN3CUY3BBeW00NGo0RDA

I would REALLY make a view like this, with the switch button, the labels between the cells of the UITableView.
This example is used more than a UITableView? Or are several separate?
I could not find any examples like this. If there is a similar example would release it for download?

Comment: lock at the bellows links 1. [iPhone UITableView Tutorial: Grouped Table](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/) 2. [IPHONE PROGRAMMING TUTORIAL: {PART 3} GROUPED UITABLEVIEW](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/20/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-3-grouped-uitableview/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate this view, create a table view controller with a 'grouped' style for the table - there's only one table. The table uses standard iOS views and styles (e.g., sections, footers, accessory views).

Section one:

- Cell one: custom cell style w/ a UILabel @ left and a UISwitch @ right
- Cell two: right detail cell style (UILabel @ left and right) and disclosure indicator accessory
- Section footer: return a UILabel w/ the text for section one by implementing  the table view delegate method 'tableView:viewForFooterInSection'.

Section two:

- Cell one: basic cell style (UILabel @ left) and disclosure indicator accessory

Section three:

- Cell one: right detail cell style (UILabel @ left and right)

With the exception of the section one footer, all of this can be easily implemented in a storyboard.

Comment: When I use a UITableView can add UISwith in a cell using the basic style, but when I use a Table View Controller I can not add UISwith in the cell when I choose the basic style.
You know why this happens?

Comment: Ahh, yes. Sorry, you'll need to set the cell style to custom and add the label and switch to that cell. I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Apple provides a few default cell styles, but as soon as you deviate from them (e.g., adding the switch), you must set the style to custom.

Comment: Then simply add a UILabel and UISwitch on top of the cell with the custom Style? Or I should add that the label through code?

Comment: Correct, you can do this in the storyboard. Drag the label and switch directly onto the cell.

Comment: I thought it would be something more complicated.
Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome. And as a note, just create an outlet in your code to the switch to get the switch's on/off state (i.e., create a weak property for the switch in your .m file via ctrl-drag).

Answer (score 0):

The view you are looking at is not a normal UITableView, it is the Settings page of Skype.

Therefore you have to have a look at Settings.bundle. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) is a link to Apples Website that is describing it. [Here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html) is a good tutorial that describes how to set up a Settings page.

**Update**: There is an open source project available that lets you include the settings page directly in your application, as you wished:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/inappsettingskit

Comment: I would like to use this view as a configuration page within the application, I will save this information for later'll use them. thank you

Comment: I would stick to Apples guidelines and export it to the Settings app. People are used to it, and you will save a lot of time configuring your UITableView. Furthermore you don't have to mess around with saving the settings somewhere.

Comment: Agreed, provided that users will not change the settings frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the free Sensible TableView framework enables you to achieve this using a very few number of lines.